# Function decoder from javascript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, byte

I have a LHT65 Sensor which sends an encoded payload and I found this code in javascript:

https://gist.github.com/koenvervloesem/c9dca322bd25a98dd042324469d0081d

```
// Source: http://www.dragino.com/downloads/downloads/LHT65/UserManual/LHT65_Temperature_Humidity_Sensor_UserManual_v1.3.pdf
function Decoder(bytes, port) {
    // Decode an uplink message from a buffer
    // (array) of bytes to an object of fields.
    var value = (bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1]) & 0x3FFF;
    var batV = value / 1000; //Battery,units:V

    value = bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[3];
    if (bytes[2] & 0x80) {
        value |= 0xFFFF0000;
    }
    var temp_SHT = (value / 100).toFixed(2); //SHT20,temperature,units:°C

    value = bytes[4] << 8 | bytes[5];
    var hum_SHT = (value / 10).toFixed(1); //SHT20,Humidity,units:%

    value = bytes[7] << 8 | bytes[8];
    if (bytes[7] & 0x80) {
        value |= 0xFFFF0000;
    }
    var temp_ds = (value / 100).toFixed(2); //DS18B20,temperature,units:°C

    return {
        BatV: batV,
        TempC_DS: temp_ds,
        TempC_SHT: temp_SHT,
        Hum_SHT: hum_SHT
    };
}
```

However I need to build the decoder in C#, so I tried this:

```
namespace SensorDecoderModule.Classes
{
    using System;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class Lht65Info
    {
        public float BatV {get; set;}
        public float  TempC_DS {get; set;}
        public float temp_SHT {get; set;}
        public float Hum_SHT {get; set;}

    }

    internal static partial class LoraDecoders
    {
        private static string Lht65_Sensor_Decoder(string devEUI, byte[] payload, byte fport)
        {
            var value = (payload[0] << 8 | payload[1]) & 0x3FFF;
            var batV = value / 1000; //Battery,units:V

            value = payload[2] << 8 | payload[3];
            if (payload[2] & 0x80) {
                value |= 0xFFFF0000;
            }
            var temp_SHT = (value / 100).toFixed(2); //SHT20,temperature,units:°C

            value = payload[4] << 8 | payload[5];
            var hum_SHT = (value / 10).toFixed(1); //SHT20,Humidity,units:%

            value = payload[7] << 8 | payload[8];
            if (payload[7] & 0x80) {
                value |= 0xFFFF0000;
            }
            var temp_ds = (value / 100).toFixed(2); //DS18B20,temperature,units:°C

            Lht65Info info = new  Lht65Info(){
               BatV = batV,
               TempC_DS = temp_ds,
               TempC_SHT = temp_SHT,
               Hum_SHT = hum_SHT
            };

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info, Formatting.Indented);
    
        }
    }
}
```

However I have several errors:

```
Decoders\Lht65_Decoder.cs(26,17): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' [C:\Users\xx\Downloads\Repos\iotedge-lorawan-starterkit-decoders\DecoderCollection\SensorDecoderModule.csproj]
Decoders\Lht65_Decoder.cs(27,17): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) [C:\Users\xx\Downloads\Repos\iotedge-lorawan-starterkit-decoders\DecoderCollection\SensorDecoderModule.csproj]
Decoders\Lht65_Decoder.cs(29,42): error CS1061: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'toFixed' and no accessible extension method 'toFixed' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\xx\Downloads\Repos\iotedge-lorawan-starterkit-decoders\DecoderCollection\SensorDecoderModule.csproj]
Decoders\Lht65_Decoder.cs(32,40): error CS1061: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'toFixed' and no accessible extension method 'toFixed' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\xx\Downloads\Repos\iotedge-lorawan-starterkit-decoders\DecoderCollection\SensorDecoderModule.csproj]
Decoders\Lht65_Decoder.cs(35,17): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' [C:\Users\xx\Downloads\Repos\iotedge-lorawan-starterkit-decoders\DecoderCollection\SensorDecoderModule.csproj]
Decoders\Lht65_Decoder.cs(36,17): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) [C:\Users\xx\Downloads\Repos\iotedge-lorawan-starterkit-decoders\DecoderCollection\SensorDecoderModule.csproj]
Decoders\Lht65_Decoder.cs(38,41): error CS1061: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'toFixed' and no accessible extension method 'toFixed' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\xx\Downloads\Repos\iotedge-lorawan-starterkit-decoders\DecoderCollection\SensorDecoderModule.csproj]
Decoders\Lht65_Decoder.cs(43,16): error CS0117: 'Lht65Info' does not contain a definition for 'TempC_SHT' [C:\Users\xx\Downloads\Repos\iotedge-lorawan-starterkit-decoders\DecoderCollection\SensorDecoderModule.csproj]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is not the same as javascript, so you cannot just copy and paste javascript code.

Javascript has one `number` type for all purposes (which corresponds to C# `double` type). So when you do this in javascipt:

```
var batV = value / 1000;
```

The result is fractional number. However when you do the same in C# (where `value` is int) - you get `int` back, so result is rounded down. So it should be:

```
var batV = value / 1000f;
```

to force `batV` to be a `float`. The same applies to other integer divisions you have (`value / 100` etc).

Then in javascript numbers which are zero (or null\undefined) are "falsy" and numbers can be used in if statements as conditions. C# doesn't have this - what you use in if statement should have boolean type. So instead of:

```
if (payload[2] & 0x80)
```

you need

```
if ((payload[2] & 0x80) != 0)
```

Then, this

```
 value |= 0xFFFF0000;
```

won't work as is, because `value` is int, but costant on the right side doesn't fit into `int` and is actually `uint` (unsigned integer). Since you don't care about actual value but only about binary respesentation - you can convert it to int with overflow:

```
value |= unchecked((int) 0xFFFF0000);
```

There is no `toFixed` function, instead you can do the same with:

```
var temp_SHT = (value / 100f).ToString("F2");
```

`ToString` (and `toFixed` in javascript) return string, while your `TempC_DS` etc properties are of type `float`. So either you need to remove conversion to string, or make said properties of type `string`.